# Android View layoutInflater get Layout by string

Tags: java, android, string, layout

having problems on android to get View with layoutInflater by using dynamically string as id.

This code works:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View newView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
scrollViewMain.removeAllViews();
scrollViewMain.addView(newView);
```

But I want to get the view dynamically by using a string like this:

```
String myString = "my_layout";
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View newView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.myString, null);
scrollViewMain.removeAllViews();
scrollViewMain.addView(newView);
```

Thanks for help understand this.

Answer (score 0):

```
String myString = "my_layout";

int layout_id= context.getResources().getIdentifier(
    myString,
    "layout",
    context.getPackageName()
);

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View newView = layoutInflater.inflate(layout_id, null);
scrollViewMain.removeAllViews();
scrollViewMain.addView(newView);
```

Comment: You Are Welcome, To Be Able To everyone Search About The Same Question To Find An Answer, Could You Mark The Correct Answer Please ?